# Вывести элементы json в ListView

Tags: android, listview, json

До этого с json не работал. Необходимо вывести элементы json в ListView.

За основу взял http://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/02/json.html.

Что нужно поменять в этом коде, если json имеет формат не

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    }
]
}
```

а просто

```
[
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
},
{
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
},
{
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Заходим в гугл и вводим "json and listview android"
И вот что мне выдало
[Тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574800/populate-listview-with-json-parser)
[Клац](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872988/loading-listview-with-json-data-using-asynctask-in-android)
[Бум](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: Если покапаться можно найти как изменить JSON (но в javascript вроде нельзя)

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите адаптер для ListView и прочитайте про inflate. Сможете выводить все что угодно.